# Possible to charge a phone battery by using built in contacts?

Tags: charger, port

Recently I had a Plum Coach Plus II handed down to me because a family member broke the charger port on the device.

I managed to charge it after a few minutes of propping and plugging in the cable slanted allowing the device to charge, but however shorts the charger after some time resulting in a false "charging" Message on the device.

My prime question is it possible to charge the battery by perhaps splicing a USB cable and attaching the ends to the contacts of the device where it meets the battery?

Many thanks!

Comment: Depends. Do you want to start a fire?

Comment: Well, being serious. Obviously not. Being one of those manufacturers that do not service repairs, if not I'm a bit out of luck.

Comment: You need a battery charger to charge a battery, and normally the device itself acts as such. The battery itself has no charge capability. You'll probably have to find a third-party repair service to replace the connector.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No it's not. If you do that, you will put 5V across the battery and the circuit which is attached to it. As lithium batteries have a maximum of 4.2V (some 4.35V) you might damage the circuit attached to it.

Batteries, especially lithium ones, need a special charging, which you will not provide with just attaching 5V from an USB cable. If you would just attach it, you will overcharge the battery (after some time) and it will end badly (fire, explosion, those sort of things).

Rechargeable devices provide an internal circuitry to handle the charging of the battery in a correct fashion.

What you could do, is take out the battery and connect it to a lithium battery charger.

The other thing which is possible is to supply the 5V at the points where they are supposed to go, but looking at my phone it doesn't seem to be simple to get anywhere close that Micro-USB-jack.

Answer (score 0):

Some models of cellphones have external battery chargers available.  For example, my Galaxy S4 and S5 phones have removable batteries.  I was able to purchase both extra batteries *AND* external chargers for those batteries.  The S4 external charger is directly powered from the AC Mains and has an additional USB charging port on the side.  The external charger for the S5 is designed to be powered from a USB charging cord - the input connector is the same as the one on the phone.

I would simply see if someone does make an external charger for your phone batteries.